# How to call a web service with multiple input (in a Script Component) in SSIS?

Tags: web-services, ssis, dataflowtask, script-component

I need to use a Web Service that allows me to perform a special calculation. To perform this I used a Web Service Task, but the problem is that I only know how to call the Web Service **once (1 input value)**, and I **need to perform** the calculation **for multiple values**.

[image]

I came up with these 2 options to achieve my goal

**Option 1:**

- In my opinion it would be better to call the Web Service in a Script Component using a Data Flow Task instead of a WS Task (but don't know how to call a WS in a Script ??).

**Option 2:**

- Keep the Web Service Task and perform the calculations for my multiple input values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to Request the Web Service from a Script Component

Find [my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20782906/606568) (updated with easy steps).

Answer (score 0):

I've used a script task to do this & used System.net.Webrequest to talk to the Web Service - works for me!

However you should also be able to set the Web Service value at run time by putting it in a for each container & using an an expression to set the value in the Web Service Task at run time.

Comment: Don't you mean 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest' ??

Comment: And is it possible to write down the steps to set the Web Service value at run time? Now, I used a script component but it gives an error at pre-compile. If you're interested --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741590/consuming-web-service-in-ssis-gives-mismatch-between-the-processor-architecture . I also sent a feedback to Microsoft, it could be an issue in SSIS --> http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812216/consuming-web-service-in-ssis-gives-mismatch-between-the-processor-architecture